# How to get a map of interfaces or superclasses in java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Suppose I have interface (or superclass, doesn't matter) `Program` and implementation `Firefox`. I would like to define a map in some classes state as `Map<Long,Program> mapOfPrograms` then in a setter set `mapOfPrograms = new TreeMap<Long,Firefox>();` through dependency injection. I need to be able to do `mapOfPrograms.put(1l,new Firefox());` or `mapOfPrograms.put(1l,(Program)(new Firefox()));` I then need to be able to `get` and use these objects.

I'm getting the error `Type Mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Long,Program> to TreeMap<Long,Firefox>`. Doesn't matter if `Program` is an interface or superclass.

How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Read about [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
class MyMap<K,T extends Program> extends TreeMap<K,Program>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}

interface Program{

}

class Firefox implements Program{

}
```

And here is your code

```
    Map<Long, Program> map=new MyMap<Long,Firefox>();
    map.put(1L, new Firefox());
```

Comment: You can define keys other than `Long` as `MyMap` is parametrized.

Comment: +1, will this solution allow me to get as well as put like normal? Why wouldn't I use `? super` ?

Comment: Find the solution here [java generics super vs. extends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133714/java-generics-super-vs-extends?answertab=votes#tab-top).